# How can I call a predefined Geb Page element using WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, geb

I created a re-usable `WebDriver` method, but I can't for the life of me figure out how I can call a predefined Geb page CSS selector using WebDriver.

This method works, but I can't seem to call it using `WebElement` element:

```
static void WaitVisibilityOfElement(WebDriver driver, By cssSelector, int timeoutInSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds)
    Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(cssSelector)).click()
}
```

This is the element I am trying to call, and I want to just be able to use the name of the element `flipperCardOne`, but if I do that it doesn't work.

```
flipperCardOne(wait:true) {$ (".flex-item:nth-child(5) .front > .w-100")}
```

Comment: How were you expecting to use your method?  A brief example would be handy.

Answer (score 1):

Geb's selector results (the things returned from calls to `$()`) are called `Navigator`s and are a wrapper around collections of Selenium's `WebElement`s. Because Navigators can be created from more than just css selectors (you can chain multiple `find()` calls on them, you can base them off xpath expressions and you can filter contents of them by matching their text, just to give a number of examples) you cannot map one to one from a `Navigator` to a css selector. If your intention is to always wait for `flipperCardOne` to be visible before interacting with it then the idiomatic way to do that would be to use [`waitCondition` content option](https://gebish.org/manual/current/#content-dsl-wait-condition):

```
flipperCardOne(wait:true, waitCondition: { it.displayed }) {$ (".flex-item:nth-child(5) .front > .w-100")}
```

Then you could just do `flipperCardOne.click()` and it would work.

And if you insist on using a method similar to what you listed in the question (and I'd argue that it's not the right thing to do) then you'd need something like:

```
static void WaitVisibilityOfElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement webElement, int timeoutInSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds)
    Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(webElement)).click()
}
```

and then call it like:

```
WaitVisibilityOfElement(browser.driver, flipperCardOne.singleElement, 5)
```

Comment: @erdi is `flipperCardOne(wait:true, waitCondition: { it.displayed })` the same as `waitFor { flipperCardOne.displayed}` ?

Comment: It's not exactly the same because calling `flipperCardOne` defined with `wait` and `waitCondition` will return a navigator and calling `waitFor { flipperCardOne.displayed}` will return a boolean but they are the same in that they won't return until the element used in the definition of `flipperCardOne` is visible.